# Why Does UI Only Update with Two Consecutive StateHasChanged() Calls in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I'm working on a Blazor Maui Hybrid project and I've noticed a behavior that I don't fully understand. In my component's `OnInitializedAsync` method, I'm subscribing to an action and updating the component's state. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var isDarkModeString = LocalPreferences?.Get(UiThemeDarkModeTogglePreferencesKey, "False") ?? "False";
    IsDarkMode = Convert.ToBoolean(isDarkModeString);

    ActionSubscriber?.SubscribeToAction<UpdateBadgesStatusesAction>(this, _ =>
    {
        UpdateTabBadges(TabPages, BadgesState?.Value?.BadgesStatuses);
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
    });

    Dispatcher?.Dispatch(new LoadBadgesStatusesAction());
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

The `UpdateTabBadges` method is defined as follows:

```cs
private void UpdateTabBadges(TabbedPanelPage[] tabs, bool[] newBadgeStatuses)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < newBadgeStatuses.Length; i++)
    {
        tabs[i].HasBadge = newBadgeStatuses[i];
    }
}
```

My component's markup includes a `MudTabs` component, and each `MudTabPanel` in the tabs has a `BadgeDot` property that gets updated when the `HasBadge` property of the corresponding `TabbedPanelPage` object is updated:

```html
<MudTabs @ref="_tabs" Outlined="true"
                         Position="Position.Bottom"
                         Rounded="true"
                         Border="true"
                         Centered="true"
                         AlwaysShowScrollButtons="false"
                         KeepPanelsAlive="true"
                         ApplyEffectsToContainer="true"
                         Elevation="5"
                         Class="mt-8 tabs-panel"
                         ActivePanelIndexChanged="StoreActiveTabIndex"
                         PanelClass="pa-6">

                    @foreach (var tabPage in TabPages)
                    {
                        <MudTabPanel ID="@tabPage.Id"
                                 Class="clickable-tab"
                                 BadgeDot="@tabPage.HasBadge"
                                 BadgeColor="Color.Success">
                            <TabContent>
                                <MudIcon Title="@tabPage.Name" Icon="@tabPage.Icon"></MudIcon>
                            </TabContent>

                            <ChildContent>
                                <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.False" Class="mud-tabs-panels">
                                    @tabPage.Component
                                </MudContainer>
                            </ChildContent>

                        </MudTabPanel>
                    }
                </MudTabs>
```

Moreover, I'm using Fluxor and I dispatch the `UpdateBadgesStatusesAction` from another component:

```cs
private void SubscribeOnAppChanges()
{
    // ...
    ActionSubscriber?.SubscribeToAction<RetrieveDevicesCompleteAction>(this, action =>
    {
        // ...
        Dispatcher?.Dispatch(new UpdateBadgesStatusesAction(Constants.SyncTabOrderNumber, isAnyConnected));
    });

    ActionSubscriber?.SubscribeToAction<UpdateDeviceConnectionStatusAction>(this, action =>
    {
        // ...
        Dispatcher?.Dispatch(new UpdateBadgesStatusesAction(Constants.SyncTabOrderNumber, isAnyConnected));
    });
}
```

What I'm having trouble understanding is why two consecutive `StateHasChanged()` calls are necessary for the UI to update correctly. If I remove one of the `StateHasChanged()` calls, the UI does not update as expected.

My understanding is that a single call to `StateHasChanged()` should be sufficient to inform Blazor that it needs to re-render the component. Could someone explain why two calls are necessary in this case? Is this a known issue with Blazor, or could it be related to some other factors in my code? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

I have debugged the `OnInitializedAsync` method and the `UpdateTabBadges` method. During the debugging process, I have confirmed that the status values and the HasBadge properties of the tabs are being updated correctly before calling `StateHasChanged()`. Therefore, I was expecting the UI to update correctly with a single call to `StateHasChanged()`.

However, I observed that the UI only updates as expected if I call `StateHasChanged()` twice in a row. If I only call `StateHasChanged()` once, the UI does not reflect the updated `HasBadge` values, even though the values are correct in the component's state. This is unexpected behavior based on my understanding of how `StateHasChanged()` should work.

To attempt to resolve this issue, I have tried various approaches, including calling `StateHasChanged()` in different places in the code and verifying that there are no asynchronous operations that could be affecting when `StateHasChanged()` is called. Despite these efforts, the problem persists. I have not been able to find a solution or a reason for this behavior in the Blazor documentation or in other resources.

Comment: This should not happen, so please double and triple check this. An [mre] would be nice, but given the Fluxor part that might be difficult. Try a single `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` first.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear:

```
//...
StateHasChanged();
StateHasChanged();
//...
```

Renders the component exactly once.  It's exactly the same as:

```
//...
StateHasChanged();
//...
```

Why?  Calling `StateHasChanged` doesn't render the component, it stacks the `RenderFragment` representing the output for the component onto the Render Queue.

This is the code you're calling.

```cs
    protected void StateHasChanged()
    {
        if (_hasPendingQueuedRender)
            return;

        if (_hasNeverRendered || ShouldRender() || _renderHandle.IsRenderingOnMetadataUpdate)
        {
            _hasPendingQueuedRender = true;

            try
            {
                _renderHandle.Render(_renderFragment);
            }
            catch
            {
                _hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The first call sets `_hasPendingQueuedRender` to true [if it wasn't already true].  As the two calls are in a block of synchronous code, there's no *UI Synchronization Context* thread time for the Renderer to run and `_hasPendingQueuedRender` is still true for the second call, and thus `StateHasChanged` doesn't do anything.

To prove it:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Diagnostics;

@{
    Debug.WriteLine($"ComponentX - {Uid} - Rendered");
}
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="m-2 p-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=Click>Click Me</button>
</div>

@code {
    private Guid Uid = Guid.NewGuid();

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ComponentX - {Uid} - Render Queued");
        return base.ShouldRender();
    }

    private Task Click()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Gives you:

```
Initializing host services...
... the intitial Render
ComponentX - 68ec1c0b-39c0-4cd4-9cab-413f6846ecd1 - Rendered 
... My button click
ComponentX - 68ec1c0b-39c0-4cd4-9cab-413f6846ecd1 - Render Queued 
ComponentX - 68ec1c0b-39c0-4cd4-9cab-413f6846ecd1 - Rendered
```

So based on the above code, I can't see how calling `StateHasChanged` twice solves the problem.

The root cause of your problem isn't there.  You're treating the symptoms, not the cause.

Also you state that your problem is in `OnInitializedAsync` when it isn't.

```cs
    ActionSubscriber?.SubscribeToAction<UpdateBadgesStatusesAction>(this, _ =>
    {
        UpdateTabBadges(TabPages, BadgesState?.Value?.BadgesStatuses);
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
    });
```

This code assigns an anonymous method to the ActionSubscriber.  It's not executed in `OnInitializedAsync`.

It's more clear when you refactor it:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var isDarkModeString = LocalPreferences?.Get(UiThemeDarkModeTogglePreferencesKey, "False") ?? "False";
    IsDarkMode = Convert.ToBoolean(isDarkModeString);

    ActionSubscriber?.SubscribeToAction<UpdateBadgesStatusesAction>(this, UpdateTabs);

    Dispatcher?.Dispatch(new LoadBadgesStatusesAction());
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

private void UpdateTabs(UpdateBadgesStatusesAction action)
{
        UpdateTabBadges(TabPages, BadgesState?.Value?.BadgesStatuses);
        StateHasChanged();
        StateHasChanged();
}
```

Your assigning the method `UpdateTabs` to the action delegate.  It's only executed when Fluxor invokes the action.

For anyone to be able to give you a definitive answer, you need to produce a *Minimal Reproducible Example*.  No one at the moment can take your code and do anything except read it.  If the problem is not in code you have included (which is probably the case), then there's nothing anyone can suggest.

My suggestion is to give each component instance a Guid ID and put in a lot of `Debug.WriteLine` statements [as in my example code above] to track what happens when, and in what sequence.

Comment: Yes, this should be the case. But the OP states "If I remove one of the StateHasChanged() calls, the UI does not update as expected." . If tat is correct it could be an interesting timing problem.

Comment: @HH yes I agree.  However, if all the code runs on the UI *Synchronisation Context* then there should be no timing issue because [Quote from MS] "At any given point in time, work is performed on exactly one thread, which yields the impression of a single logical thread. **No two operations execute concurrently**."  There's no indication in the question that there's a timer running or some manual thread switching, but if it is a timing issue, as we both suspect, then there's some stuff going on we aren't being shown.

Comment: The OP did state it's about MAUI Hybrid. Did you try your code on that platform?

Comment: I attempted to replicate the issue using a minimal reproducible example, but everything functioned as expected there. After reworking the component, the problem was resolved.

In my original question, I forgot to mention that in the second component — from which I dispatched the action to update the badges in the first component — the statuses for badges were received from another thread by subscribing to an event raised by the attached devices. However, I used InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) for context synchronization.